# Best way to introspect an object in django templates?

Tags: django, python-3.x

We can see the attributes and methods of an object by using dir(object_name) in django views in the views.py file. 
I want to introspect an object in django template in this case the variable message.

```
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>
                {{ message }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: `{{ message.__dict__ }}`? `{{ message.__dict__.__str__ }}`?

Comment: I'm getting errors that says -

Comment: Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores: 'message.__dict__'

Comment: Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores: 'message.__dict__.__str__'

Comment: Then try `{{ message|pprint }}` :)

Comment: All I get is this - 
<django.contrib.messages.storage.base.Message object at 0x000002FBC45FF358>

Comment: @Pawamoy,  Thanks for your help. I figured out a solution ;-)

Comment: You're welcome :) One last idea: add `{% debug %}` somewhere in your template. It will print the context and other info.

Comment: {% debug %} prints lots of stuff, it prints the stuff I was not looking for :P 
Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it :)
Below code does what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a [custom Django filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) as below:

```
@register.filter
    def dirs(value):
        return str(dir(value))
```

Load custom filter into the template:

```
{% load filters %}
```

Then use it as below:

```
{{ message|dirs }}
```